# Apache version upgrade issue

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf

At present we are on Apache/2.2.15 (UNIX) version. To fix the vulnerabilities we are suggested to upgrade to new version. I got new version from online using "wget" command and followed steps mentioned on this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html#download.

Once I am done, checked version using httpd -v. It gives me old version Apache/2.2.15 (UNIX). If I check using /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd - v. It gives me new version. Did I successfully upgraded the version or not? If not what should I do?

I tried "yum install httpd" - It says "Nothing to do".

[image]

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text. Just post the text of interest, edited for brevity as much as possible.

Comment: This sounds as if you are just trying around, here mixing different forms of installation. That never is a good idea. Is the old installation based on packages and the local software management? Or is that a "wild installation" too?

Comment: And btw: why do you download version 2.2? Current stable and well proven is 2.4...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You now have two versions of Apache installed.  You have the one installed with the system package manager (`yum`) in `/usr/sbin/httpd`.  You have one installed manually in `/usr/local/apache2/...`.

Which one you get will be determined entirely by which path you use.

In general, mixing system-managed packages with manually installed packages is a recipe for trouble. If you want to stick with the newer version in `/usr/local`, you should remove the system version, and realize that you will lose some manageability.  For example, you will no longer be able to use `yum install ...` to install new Apache modules, and you will not be able to verify the installed files using tools like `rpmverify`.

If your distribution currently has Apache 2.2.x, that suggests your distribution is fairly old.  For example, RHEL (and CentOS) 7 (and similar variants) have version 2.4.6 packaged, so you may want to update your host to something newer than whatever you're running now.

Comment: @user3781360 your next step is to disable the original httpd daemon, then enable the new one saved in /usr/local. How you accomplish that depends on whether your system uses the newer systemd services or the original SystemV init.d services.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its successfully upgraded as per the screenshot.

- httpd 2.2.15 is the version with RHEL 6 repository, here HTTPD_HOME is /etc/httpd (Highest version provided for HTTPD via RPM RHEL 6 is 2.2.15)
- httpd 2.4.6 is the version with EPEL-HTTPD24 repository, here HTTPD_HOME is /usr/local/apache2/